# Modify DataFrame based on another DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dataframes

```
df1

       Product     Quantity   Price  Description
  0    bread           3        12    desc1
  1    cookie          5        10    desc2
  2    milk            7        15    desc3
  3    sugar           4        7     desc4
  4    chocolate       5        9     desc5



 df2
           Attribute   Configuration
      0    Product           C       
      1    Quantity          C       
      2    Price             D        
      3    Description       D
```

What I'm trying to do is if the letter *D* is in the *Configuration* column in df2. The entire row is deleted in df1.

So that df2 is like the way to create another dataframe with the configuration that this gives me.

The condition could be...

```
if df2.Configuration == 'D'
   df1.drop when df1.header = df2.Attribute
```

I kind of give that idea but I'm not sure it's like that. What I can do?

The result should look like this...

```
df3

       Product     Quantity  
  0    bread           3      
  1    cookie          5        
  2    milk            7       
  3    sugar           4        
  4    chocolate       5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
df1.drop(df2.loc[df2.Configuration=='D','Attribute'].tolist(),1)
     Product  Quantity
0      bread         3
1     cookie         5
2       milk         7
3      sugar         4
4  chocolate         5
```